# Javascript - adding more on.change options

Tags: javascript, ajax

I currently have an **AJAX** script set up on my website which updates a table based on a selection from a dropdown menu `[id="afl_player_ID"]`.

What I want to be able to do though is have the same script run if either `[id="afl_player_ID"]` or `[id="afl_stat_ID"]` is changed.

How do I go about adding this functionality into this code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var valueCheck;
    jQuery("#afl_player_ID").on("change", function () {
        player_ID = $("#afl_player_ID").val();
        stat_ID = $("#afl_stat_ID").val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: {
                action: "call_advanced_player_basic_gamelog",
                player_ID: player_ID,
                stat_ID: stat_ID
            },
            success: function (output) {
                jQuery("#advanced_player_basic_gamelog").html(output);
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can add both IDs and attach change event to both `jQuery('#afl_player_ID, #afl_stat_ID').on('change'...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code below as suggested by @Farooq Khan in the comments

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    var valueCheck;
    jQuery('#afl_player_ID,#afl_stat_ID').on( 'change', function () {
         player_ID = $('#afl_player_ID').val();
         stat_ID = $('#afl_stat_ID').val();
     jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {
            action: 'call_advanced_player_basic_gamelog',
            player_ID: player_ID,
            stat_ID: stat_ID,
        },
         success:function(output){
             jQuery('#advanced_player_basic_gamelog').html( output );
         }
     });
    }).change();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly, I knew it would be something simple. Really appreciate you taking the time to respond.